# Is Guice continuing in progress and consummate enough for enterprise application?

Tags: java, guice, guice-3

Guice project is not active for a long time, isn't it, what's the situation of Guice?
Is Guice3 suitable for enterprise application?
Who can tell me?

Comment: Maybe they realized that you don't need a framework to do IoC. :)

Comment: Sure, it's applicable for enterprise use; it's used in most Java applications at Google.  Work on the successor to Guice is happening, though, but that's still in early days.  But Guice's lack of activity is an indicator of stability, not of irrelevance.